# Custom Google Analytics report that displays number of specific events fired per page

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, event-tracking

For a given page I fire four events based on how much of a post they consume (ArticleLoaded, StartReading, ContentBottom, PageBottom).

What I'd like to do is:

A) Create a view with 5 columns: Page title, and then one for each of the four event (Title, Load, Read, Content, and Page Bottom)

B) If possible, create a custom 6th column that simply divides Load by Content Bottom to give me a completion percentage.

I can load a simple view that has each event broken up but I can't seem to figure out how to compress the view so I can list all 4 (ideally 5) values on the same line horizontally.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you can not do this with custom reports inside google analytics.

My best advice is that you export in CVS the report and work it out in another platform (Data Studio, Klipfolio, even a simple spreadsheet may be good).

EDIT: I was assuming you don't have Analytics 360, if you have then yes you can but idk how.

Comment: Ha, I don't, no.  And yes, I was quickly coming to the realization that I can do in Excel in minutes what I'd otherwise struggle for hours to accomplish in GA.  Why bother.   Thanks.